# How can I prevent saving a relationship in Entity Framework 4.1?

Tags: entity-framework

we are using EF 4.1

and we have dummy object that should not be saved (.CanBeSaved = false)

I can prevent the saving of the object with this code

```
IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes = this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted);


    foreach (ObjectStateEntry stateEntryEntity in changes)
        if (!((MyPersistentEntityClass)stateEntryEntity.Entity).CanBeSaved)
           stateEntryEntity.ChangeState(EntityState.Unchanged);
```

but now it fails because EF is still trying to save the new relationship on added object.

How can I tell EF to not save the new relationship ?

** More Info **

The thing is sometimes we want to save the related object and other times we don't want to save the related object

Let's say we have a product object that store an image , we want to save both object. But if the product as in image of type NullImage (our custom object, that has default properties) we don't want to save the NullImage object (where .CanBeSaved is false)

we don't want to save the image or the relationship in this case only
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mark the relationship with the `[NotMapped]` attribute:

```
public class Product {
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // ...

    [NotMapped]
    public Shelf Shelf { get; set; }
}
```